# Use jQuery to return a message for all click events except save for Drupal7 form

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I can't seem to figure out why my message displays when I click "Save" in spite of the fact that I've written logic so it won't. The class name returned by the click event is 'form-submit' and the logical operators are valid...

```
Drupal.behaviors.saveOrExit = {
    attach: function (context, settings){
        p = location.pathname;
        if (p == '/user/1248/edit/configuration_1'){
            $(document).click(function(event) {
                if(event.target.className !== 'form-submit'){
                         $(window).trigger("unload");
                        window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
                        return "Your changes have not been saved! Do you really want to leave?" 
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }
};
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought it may be how you reference the class name

Maybe refer to the elements class name as

```js
if($(this).attr("class") !== 'form-submit')
```

Also check that the class name and the 'form-submit' are of the same type else use != instead of !==

Comment: Thanks, Lawrence, but no luck. Using "this" doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so apparently this is a fairly common question, but I didn't find anything on SO that worked for me. This approach (thanks Max Morrow!) works well.

http://maxmorrow.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/jquery-prevent-a-user-from-leaving-a-page-with-unsaved-data/#comment-305